# ReactiveUI WPF ApplicationCommands not working

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I have a WPF App with ReactiveUI where I use for keyboard shortcuts the following code

In my XAML file

```
<KeyBinding x:Name="OpenFileKeyBinding" Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="O"></KeyBinding>
```

In my XAML.cs

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.FileOpenCommand, v => v.OpenFileKeyBinding).DisposeWith(cleanup);
```

In my ViewModel

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> FileOpenCommand { get; set; }


FileOpenCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => { OpenFile(); });
```

This works, but recently I've seen you can bind some common simple commands using applicationcommands
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.applicationcommands?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

So I've tried the following

```
<RibbonApplicationMenuItem  x:Name="MenuFileOpen" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Menu_File_Open}" ImageSource="{svgc:SvgImage Source='pack://application:,,,/Resources/ApplicationToolbar/file_open.svg'}" Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"/>                      
   

 this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.FileOpenCommand, v => v.MenuFileOpen).DisposeWith(cleanup);
```

This does nothing and my OpenFile() method is not called.

Is there something I do wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Based on title you have error, so what kind of error do you see?

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I've updated title, I had an error previously because I was binding FileOpenCommand to MenuFileOpen.Command which was not ok. Now I have no errors, just a code doing nothing.